# Create UPS Return Label via REST API

Tags: shipping-method, ups

Trying to understand the proper way to create a return label via the UPS API. Use case is the customer needs to send back the product when they are finished using it. In the documentation I see a parameter called "Return Service" within the "Shipment" object. Is the correct workflow to make a new call using the Shipment method and include the "Return Service" parameter with the proper "Code"?